# Filtrando informação do .JSON

Tags: python, json, api

tenho o seguinte script:

```
import json
import requests


def clima_semana():

    requisicao = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Rio de Janeiro&appid=233183ebc19d6700af2a1192a9c4bf74')
    previsao = json.loads(requisicao.text)

    return previsao['list'][0]['weather'][0]['description']
```

Esta função consome uma API de previsão do tempo de 5 dias, de 3 em 3 horas, mas eu preciso apenas da descrição do tempo dos dias, em um horário apenas. Reparem como eu tive que indexar para chegar ao resultado! E este é apenas o primeiro dia, a estrutura é monstruosa (listas dentro de dicionários que contém mais dicionários, etc).

Como faço para fazer um `get` só da informação que eu preciso? Existe alguma outra técnica para resolver este problema? O tempo de execução também ficou super lento.

Comment: Quem dita o retorno do JSON é a API, se esse endpoint não está lhe atendendo, talvez você possa consumir algum outro: https://openweathermap.org/api

Comment: Não deixe a chave da API exposta a visualização é publica e podem fazer mal uso dela.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode ser mais claro sobre o que você precisa desse Json? Pode ser qualquer hora de um certo dia ? Tem que ser um horário específico ?

Você pode encapsular a sua lógica em uma outra função:

```
def GetDescricaoDoClima(dia, hora):
    return previsao['list'][dia]['weather'][hora]['description']
```

Dia e hora serão a posição nas listas do json. Boa sorte!